# how to make simple php and mysql query to make table of product and stock

Tags: php, mysql

i need a help

assumptions that i have 2 table

table1 : product

```
 ----------------------------- 
| id |  Code | any else field |
 ----------------------------- 
| 10 | GA 12 | -------------- |
| 11 | GA 1  | -------------- |
 -----------------------------
```

table2 : stock

```
 ---------------------------------------------
| id | product_id |    color    | size | stock |
 ---------------------------------------------
| 1  |   10       | Black       | M    | 12    |
| 2  |   10       | Yellow      | L    | 10    | 
| 3  |   10       | Black       | S    | 12    |
| 4  |   10       | Yellow      | XL   | 10    | 
| 5  |   10       | Red         | S    | 10    | 
| 6  |   10       | Black       | XL   | 12    |
| 7  |   10       | Yellow      | M    | 10    | 
| 8  |   10       | Red         | L    | 12    |
| 9  |   10       | Red         | XL   | 12    |
| 10 |   10       | Gray        | M    | 12    |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

from the table we can see

for product_id 10 have 4 colors

```
Black with size S M and XL
Red with size S L and XL
yellow M L and XL
Gray M
```

that mean size range for product_id 10 is S - XL

from that 2 table i need a result on my website as below

[image: Produk and stock detail]

and i have try using php and mysql query as below:

```
function getProduct(){
    $Condb = @new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $Condb->connect_errno and die ('Connect Failed : '.$Condb->connect_error);
    $sql = "
        SELECT product.*
        FROM product
        ";
    $res2 = $Condb->query($sql);
    while ($row = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
        $return_data[] = $row;
    }
    $res2->close();
    $Condb->close();            
    $return ['data'] = $return_data;                
    return $return;
}
```

--

```
function list_stock($product_id){
    $Condb = @new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $Condb->connect_errno and die ('Connect Failed : '.$Condb->connect_error);

    //Distinct to get size range from product_id
    $sql = "
        SELECT DISTINCT size FROM stock WHERE product_id='$product_id' 
        ORDER BY uk ASC
        ";
    $res2 = $Condb->query($sql);
    $return_size_range = array();
    while ($row = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
        $return_size_range[] = $row['size'];
    }
    $res2->close();

    $return_stock[] = array();
    $return_color = array();
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM stock
        WHERE product_id='$product_id'
        GROUP BY product_id, color, size                
        ORDER BY warna, uk ASC
        ";
   $res2 = $Condb->query($sql);
   $n = 0;
   $w = 0;
   while ($row = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
      $size_index = 0;
      if($n%count($return_size_range)== 0){
          $color=$row['color'];
          $return_color[$w]=$color;
          $w=$w+1;
          $n=0;
      }

      while($size_index == 0){
          if($return_size_range[$n] == $row['size']){
              $sz = $row['size'];

              $return_stock[$n]['size' . $color] = $sz;
          $return_stock[$n]['stock' . $color . $sz] = $row['stock'];
              $size_index=1;
          }else{
              $size_index=0;
          }
          $n += 1;
      }
   }
   $res2->close();
   $Condb->close();
   $return ['color'] = $return_color;               
   $return ['size'] = $return_size_range;               
   $return ['stock'] = $return_stock;               
   return $return;
}
```

for html i use below code :

```
<?php
    $product = getProduct();
    $product_detail = $product['data'];
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <!-- header of table -->
    <tr>
    <?php
    for($p=0 ; $p<count($produk_detail); $p++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <!-- produk_detail -->
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <!-- with colspan from produk detail column -->
           <?php
               $stock_detail = list_stock($product_detail[$p]['id']);
               $size = $stock_detail['size'];
               $color = $stock_detail['color'];
               $stock = $stock_detail['stock'];
           ?>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>color</td>
                   <?php
                   for($s=0; $s<count($size); $s++){
                       echo '<td>' . $size[$s] . '</td>';
                   }
                   ?>

               </tr>
               <?php
               for($c=0; $c<count($color); $c++){
               ?>
               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $color[$c]; ?></td>
                   <?php
                   for($st=0; $st<count($size); $st++){
                       echo '<td>';
                       echo isset($stock[$st]['stock' . $color[$c] . $size[st]]) ? $stock[$st]['stock' . $color[$c] . $size[st]] : 0;
                       echo '</td>';
                   }
                   ?>
               </tr>  
               <?php
               }                      
               ?>


               <tr>

               </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
    <tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

<table>
```

based on above source code, i success to get the result as image i attached, 
but the code is very long, and make loading slow to get the product and stock detail,

is this possible to make more simple of source code(php) and mysql query from my source code?? 
or is this possible to get result as image attched with simple php and mysql query??

thanks

Comment: Are all size values known up-front and should be all presented for every product? Or it should be dynamic?

Comment: yes, all size value must be present below of produk detail..

Comment: I meant do they always the same for **all** products?

Comment: no, size is depend of size field of stock table, because some product isi using number of size range, for example :  38 - 43(38, 39, 40, 41, 42 43) or 32 - 35 (32, 33, 34, 35)